# Installing struct-lmm on Mac M2

Tags: gcc, homebrew, apple-m1

I am trying to install [this package](https://anaconda.org/conda-forge/struct-lmm) both in *ex novo* conda environment and in my default python environment however, in both cases, I have problems. My current laptop is a Mac air with M2 Apple Silicon chip

The first error that came out was a dependency error which I fixed trying to install before the package `numpy-sugar` from the same author. Then re-running the command to install `struct-lmm` I obtained an error installing `liknorm` (always from the same author). Here the error was `` ` ``uilding wheels for collected packages: liknorm
Building wheel for liknorm (pyproject.toml): started
Building wheel for liknorm (pyproject.toml): finished with status 'error'
Failed to build liknorm

error: subprocess-exited-with-error

× Building wheel for liknorm (pyproject.toml) did not run successfully.
│ exit code: 1
╰─> [65 lines of output]
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/urllib/request.py", line 1348, in do_open
h.request(req.get_method(), req.selector, req.data, headers,
File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/http/client.py", line 1282, in request
self._send_request(method, url, body, headers, encode_chunked)
File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/http/client.py", line 1328, in _send_request
self.endheaders(body, encode_chunked=encode_chunked)
File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/http/client.py", line 1277, in endheaders
self._send_output(message_body, encode_chunked=encode_chunked)
File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/http/client.py", line 1037, in _send_output
self.send(msg)
File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/http/client.py", line 975, in send
self.connect()
File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/http/client.py", line 1454, in connect
self.sock = self._context.wrap_socket(self.sock,
File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/ssl.py", line 513, in wrap_socket
return self.sslsocket_class._create(
File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/ssl.py", line 1071, in _create
self.do_handshake()
File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/ssl.py", line 1342, in do_handshake
self._sslobj.do_handshake()
ssl.SSLCertVerificationError: [SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: unable to get local issuer certificate (_ssl.c:997)

```
  During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
  
  Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "/private/var/folders/6k/jgw_wc512zv_x7mm7j6qlwb4t_5zjb/T/pip-install-pgk_t08q/liknorm_be1352084a4a4ed7b5e510f54fcfc0f9/build_ext.py", line 118, in <module>
      compile_extension()
    File "/private/var/folders/6k/jgw_wc512zv_x7mm7j6qlwb4t_5zjb/T/pip-install-pgk_t08q/liknorm_be1352084a4a4ed7b5e510f54fcfc0f9/build_ext.py", line 92, in compile_extension
      build_deps(pwd, "limix", "liknorm", "1.5.8")
    File "/private/var/folders/6k/jgw_wc512zv_x7mm7j6qlwb4t_5zjb/T/pip-install-pgk_t08q/liknorm_be1352084a4a4ed7b5e510f54fcfc0f9/build_ext.py", line 46, in build_deps
      with urllib.request.urlopen(url) as rf:
    File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/urllib/request.py", line 216, in urlopen
      return opener.open(url, data, timeout)
    File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/urllib/request.py", line 519, in open
      response = self._open(req, data)
    File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/urllib/request.py", line 536, in _open
      result = self._call_chain(self.handle_open, protocol, protocol +
    File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/urllib/request.py", line 496, in _call_chain
      result = func(*args)
    File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/urllib/request.py", line 1391, in https_open
      return self.do_open(http.client.HTTPSConnection, req,
    File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/urllib/request.py", line 1351, in do_open
      raise URLError(err)
  urllib.error.URLError: <urlopen error [SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: unable to get local issuer certificate (_ssl.c:997)>
  Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "/Users/antonio.nappi/Desktop/Github_projects/mtgwas/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pip/_vendor/pep517/in_process/_in_process.py", line 351, in <module>
      main()
    File "/Users/antonio.nappi/Desktop/Github_projects/mtgwas/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pip/_vendor/pep517/in_process/_in_process.py", line 333, in main
      json_out['return_val'] = hook(**hook_input['kwargs'])
    File "/Users/antonio.nappi/Desktop/Github_projects/mtgwas/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pip/_vendor/pep517/in_process/_in_process.py", line 249, in build_wheel
      return _build_backend().build_wheel(wheel_directory, config_settings,
    File "/private/var/folders/6k/jgw_wc512zv_x7mm7j6qlwb4t_5zjb/T/pip-build-env-4tcwstdw/overlay/lib/python3.10/site-packages/poetry/core/masonry/api.py", line 56, in build_wheel
      return WheelBuilder.make_in(
    File "/private/var/folders/6k/jgw_wc512zv_x7mm7j6qlwb4t_5zjb/T/pip-build-env-4tcwstdw/overlay/lib/python3.10/site-packages/poetry/core/masonry/builders/wheel.py", line 85, in make_in
      wb.build(target_dir=directory)
    File "/private/var/folders/6k/jgw_wc512zv_x7mm7j6qlwb4t_5zjb/T/pip-build-env-4tcwstdw/overlay/lib/python3.10/site-packages/poetry/core/masonry/builders/wheel.py", line 120, in build
      self._build(zip_file)
    File "/private/var/folders/6k/jgw_wc512zv_x7mm7j6qlwb4t_5zjb/T/pip-build-env-4tcwstdw/overlay/lib/python3.10/site-packages/poetry/core/masonry/builders/wheel.py", line 169, in _build
      self._run_build_script(self._package.build_script)
    File "/private/var/folders/6k/jgw_wc512zv_x7mm7j6qlwb4t_5zjb/T/pip-build-env-4tcwstdw/overlay/lib/python3.10/site-packages/poetry/core/masonry/builders/wheel.py", line 229, in _run_build_script
      subprocess.check_call([self.executable.as_posix(), build_script])
    File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/subprocess.py", line 369, in check_call
      raise CalledProcessError(retcode, cmd)
  subprocess.CalledProcessError: Command '['/Users/antonio.nappi/Desktop/Github_projects/mtgwas/venv/bin/python', 'build_ext.py']' returned non-zero exit status 1.
  [end of output] note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip. ERROR: Failed building wheel for liknorm ERROR: Could not build wheels for liknorm, which is required to install pyproject.toml-based projec"
```

as suggested by ChatGPT, I tried to rerun the command with

`pip install --trusted-host pypi.org --trusted-host files.pythonhosted.org liknorm`

and then I found the error was in `[cffi`](https://cffi.readthedocs.io/en/latest/installation.html#platform-specific-instructions) with the following error

```
 gcc: warning: this compiler does not support x86 ('-arch' option ignored)             gcc: error: unrecognized command-line option '-iwithsysroot/usr/include/ffi'             error: command '/opt/homebrew/bin/gcc' failed with exit code 1             [end of output]
```

To install `cffi` it requires `hombebrew` so I run `/bin/bash -c "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/HEAD/install.sh)"`  then I installed gcc `brew install gcc` and modified the CC env variable `export CC=/opt/homebrew/bin/gcc`  My gcc however still can't manage x86 C files, so I run `arch -x86_64 brew install gcc`  and I got the error `Error: Cannot install under Rosetta 2 in ARM default prefix (/opt/homebrew)! To rerun under ARM use:     arch -arm64 brew install ... To install under x86_64, install Homebrew into /usr/local.` To install homebrew in `usr/local` I tried to modify the `install.sh` file but it didn't work. I know that I can download the `.tar.gz` file but it's not supported, how can I fix it in a proper way? If the manual installation is the only option, how can I install the `tar.gz` file?